# How to parse RequestBody in Play Framework (Java)

Tags: java, http, post, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to parse the RequestBody of a POST, currently I am doing the following:

```
public static Result createMessages(){
     RequestBody body = request().body();
     return ok("Got body: " + body);
}
```

This results in the following being returned to the browser:

```
Got body: DefaultRequestBody(None,None,None,None,None,Some(MultipartFormData(Map(from -> List(Hello), message -> List(World), subject -> List(Test)),List(),List(),List())),false)
```

I need to get the MultipartFormData from this output as you can see it has the posted values, but unsure how to do this in Java Play

Answer (score 0):

Handling multipart forms is nice documented at [Play's docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFileUpload)

For other form fields you can easily use ie. [`DynamicForm`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html)